# Debug VB6 .ocx consumed by Access application

Tags: ms-access, vb6, activex, ocx

i have an old VB6 activeX .ocx source code that i am trying to tweak it to my needs.
The problem is that i am using it on Access Application and its quite time consuming to get some info for its behavior.
Right now i am compiling the .ocx , transfering it to System32 , unregister the previous .ocx, register the new and rerunning the Access application.
It would be just great if i could interact with the VB6 IDE thus catching all the info the .ocx is getting from Access without relying on msgboxes

TIA

Comment: You can register it anywhere you like on your development PC, doesn't need to be system32.

Comment: I thought  in the VB6 system, there is a "wait" for object creating or some option that allows you to specify the command line option of the program in question to be "launched" when you whack debug in VB6 IDE. What this does is then launch your specified (command line) program. Because the program is launched by/from the VB6 IDE, then your break points and tracing of code works. This also works in the .net IDE. I create class objects in net all the time for use with Access. You can't "run" the .net class, but if you setup the command line to launch access, then I can single step class code.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal is correct